# Количество ресурсов на обслуживание интернет подключения

Tags: сеть

Сколько нужно ресурсов компьютера для обслуживания интернет подключений?
Есть ли формула расчета?
Интересует для ОС Ubuntu

Comment: 1 ресурс - сетевая карта.

Comment: @edem я не правильно выразился, сколько оперативной памяти и процессора нужно для обработки соединения.